# Can a Linux Jenkins stop / start an IIS website during pipeline build?

Tags: iis, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I'm currently trying to build a php application in a Linux Jenkins server and then publishing the build artifacts to a remote windows server using IIS via a the Publish Over CIFS plugin.

However, if the app is in use the plugin Publish Over CIFS will not allow me to write to the windows share, saying that it is in use. This makes me believe that I need to somehow start/stop the IIS website while publishing.

Has anyone had experience with this? Is there a better way to publish PHP Artifacts from Jenkins on Linux to a separate remote windows IIS server?

Comment: Install IIS REST API https://github.com/Microsoft/IIS.Administration and then in your build script you can consume it to control IIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what we ended up doing, however there are some other suggestions that are worth looking into:

- Installed openssh on the windows server that we were pushing to
- Use ssh from the jenkins server (linux) to run a powershell command on windows to stop the website
- Command was: ssh user@host 'powershell.exe -Command Start-Website name'

Answer (score 0):

If you can setup a Jenkins agent in the Windows server, then you can use IIS app command in Jenkins build step to start / stop your IIS

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can:) you have to make sure that jenkins has permission to start and stop the IIS server i.e. jenkins has to have admin privileges

**EDITED**

How to add a user to admin group 
https://www.isunshare.com/windows-server/add-a-user-to-local-administrator-group.html

After this you can use the start and stop commands for starting and stopping IIS server in command line (wirte a bat script)

```
STOP-net stop WAS
START-net start W3SVC
```

Comment: Our Jenkins server was separate from the IIS server. Our Jenkins server is also running using Linux

Comment: Doesn't matter where jenkins is as along as jenkins can communicate with windows which is already happening(you are transferring the files) all you need to do is give permission to jenkins as an admin or give him permission in IIS application group

Comment: How will a Linux box run a batch script? Sorry, I'm not very familiar with devops tbh. See my accepted answer for what we do now. Let me know if you still think that batch script is better. Also, the only way we communicate with the windows iis server is through the publishovercifs plugin to drop files.

Comment: actually linux doesn't care what the extension is, it will run it if it finds the first line i.e. #!/bin/bash so you can have a file called "jenkins.iis" and it will work :D , that's the beauty of linux...This is just an alternative solution which you can think of , useful if you plan to move into pipeline feature in jenkins when you want more control :)